# String size limitation on WebBrowserTask.URL in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone-7, browser

I'm trying to call a web service from my app but for some reason it cuts the string short that I pass to WebBrowserTask.URL... So I don't know if there's some sort of string limitation on it?

Obviously the call fails where it's supposed to return me a pdf document since the URL is cut short. Below is the code that I'm using. I can't provide you with a patientGuid and sessionID but for reference each of those is about 16 characters long

```
 WebBrowserTask browser = new WebBrowserTask();
 browser.URL = string.Format("https://secure.lancet.co.za/Patriarch/patient?sid={0}&patientGuid={1}&f=CUM.PAT.PDF", Uri.EscapeDataString(sessionID), Uri.EscapeDataString(patientGuid));
 browser.Show();
```

Thanks for any help!

Update: the total size of my URL ends up being 149 characters.

Comment: The URL property is obsolete. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.webbrowsertask(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: @ta.speot.is - Thanks for pointing that out! Although when I use brower.Uri the property is not found on the WebBrowserTask object? I've tried viewing another pdf on the web using this code and it worked fine. Which leads me to think some string limitation is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Uri.EscapeDataString("&") for escaping "&" in your url string.